# Variable scope in pine script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

Here I am using a few variables to set my exit conditions by the way of defining `profit` or `stop` in ticks

```
stopLR          = float(floor(stopLoss))    - (3* syminfo.mintick)
targetLR        = float(floor(target))      - (3* syminfo.mintick

if(longCondition and strategy.position_size == 0)
    //average_long    = close
    targetLTick     := (targetLR - close) / syminfo.mintick
    stopLTick       := (close - stopLR) / syminfo.mintick
    

strategy.exit("Long Buy",   profit = targetLTick,   comment = "Take Profit")  //line 460
strategy.exit("Long Buy",   loss = stopLTick,       comment = "Book Loss")    //line 461
```

> Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 460: Undeclared identifier 'targetLTick';

> line 461: Undeclared identifier 'stopLTick'

What is the problem here ?
Variables are of global scope and no problem with spellings, why is pine giving me error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your snippet, `targetLTick` and `stopLTick` are declared in the local scope.
Try to declare them in the global scope with `na` value and then re-assign in the local scope as in the example below:

```
stopLR          = float(floor(stopLoss))    - (3* syminfo.mintick)
targetLR        = float(floor(target))      - (3* syminfo.mintick

var float targetLTick = na     
var float stopLTick = na
       
if(longCondition and strategy.position_size == 0)
    //average_long    = close
    targetLTick     := (targetLR - close) / syminfo.mintick
    stopLTick       := (close - stopLR) / syminfo.mintick
    

strategy.exit("Long Buy",   profit = targetLTick,   comment = "Take Profit")  //line 460
strategy.exit("Long Buy",   loss = stopLTick,       comment = "Book Loss")    //line 461
```

Comment: I did what you asked, but it didn't work. I also tried using targetLTick = 0.0, but that didn't work either. if you want, I can post the whole code, but I think I've posted the relevant parts

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, I did a label.new() to see what is going wrong, the tick calculation is fine but for some reason, the strategy won't exit there and my position closed EOD because of my strategy.close_all

Comment: And I have encountered the strangest thing, when I set stopLTick = 0.0, strategy would exit in the next candle itself, and with stopLTick = na, it would be global exit. Something tells me that the strategy.exit is not interpreting the ticks correctly...

Comment: I think I've got it, pine cannot handle multiple strategy.exit() for the same entry